# How to create and move a navigation icon/image in MapBox JS (WEB)

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox provides amazing tools for visualizing maps and moving around them. I was able to plot a line of coordinate points along a road but couldn't figure out how to create and move an icon that represents a vehicle traversing the path. The best I could get was a surface level marker, but it only allows the default marker image.

What I'm looking to create is something like this:
[Navigation Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJy5R.png)

The main issue is symbols can't be moved after being added as layers to the map.

```
// Load Icon
        this.map.addImage('pulsing-dot', pulsingDot, { pixelRatio: 2 });

        this.map.addSource('dot-point', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': {
                'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                'features': [
                    {
                        'id': 'icon-source',
                        'type': 'Feature',
                        'geometry': {
                            'type': 'Point',
                            'coordinates': pulsingDot.coords // icon position [lng, lat]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
        this.map.addLayer({
            'id': 'layer-with-pulsing-dot',
            'type': 'symbol',
            'source': 'dot-point',
            'layout': {
                'icon-image': 'pulsing-dot',
                'icon-pitch-alignment': 'map'
            }
        });
```

However, upon running the code below the icon position is not updated in the map view.

```
            pulsingDot.setLngLat(coords);
            this.map.setFeatureState({
                source: 'dot-point',
                id: 'icon-source',
            }, {
                geometry: {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': pulsingDot.coords // icon position [lng, lat]
                }
            });
```

Is there a way to "update a layer" for changes made to the source? or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?